# how to fetch the row of two joined tables where the data in the second table is the last updated?

Tags: mysql, laravel-8

Table A

```
id   p_mid   p_name      p_date
---------------------------------
0    ka001    raw        2020/1/1
1    ka002    res        2021/1/1
2    sha001   rey        2022/1/1
```

Table B

```
id   rep_id  observers  registered_date
---------------------------------------
0     0      Joan         2020/2/1
1     0      Kevin        2020/3/1
2     0      Andria       2020/4/1
3     1      Peter        2021/1/1
4     1      Peter        2021/2/1
5     2      Ros          2022/3/1
6     2      John         2022/4/1
```

I need to query the above tables to give me a joined result of both, where the second table only show the latest updated row like this:

```
id  p_mid  p_name  p_date  rep_id  observers  registered_date
--------------------------------------------------------------

0   ka001  raw     2020/1/1   0     Andria     2020/4/1 
1   ka002  res     2021/1/1   1     Peter      2021/2/1 
2   sha001 rey     2022/1/1   2     John       2022/4/1
```

I also used latest() function instead of orderBy and first()-project_id, but it did not solve it.Here Table A.id has relation with Table B.rep_id.

Answer (score 0):

```
$search = $request->re_search; 

$search_result = DB::table('projects')-> join('project__reports','projects.id',"=",'project__reports.project_id') 
->select('projects.id','projects.Pmid','projects.Ministry', 'projects.P_name','projects.Budget','project__reports.prgs_prc', 'project__reports.observers','project__reports.added_fund','project__reports.Registered_at') 
->where('projects.Ministry','LIKE',"%{$search}%") 
-> orderBy('project__reports.Registered_at','desc')->first()->project_id;
```

Your logic is correct. Its just that you didn't define project_id on your select statement. or try this below code.

```
first()->id;
```

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question and showed exactly what I need to retrieve but I tried all the above functions and the did not work.

Comment: Is your rep_id reference to id on Table A?

Comment: yes, I have one to many relationship between Table A.id and Table B.rep_id  and I need to get the results as I showed in the third table above, I believe my logic is wrong because I tried many ways and at the very good point it only gives me one row among them all

Answer (score 0):

```
$search = $request->re_search; 

$search_result = DB::table('tableA')-> join('tableB','tableA.id',"=",'tableB.rep_id') 
->select('tableA.id','tableB.rep_id','tableA.p_mid', 'tableA.p_name','tableA.p_date','tableB.observers', 'tableB.registered_date') 
->where('tableA.p_name','LIKE',"%{$search}%") 
-> orderBy('tableB.registered_date','desc')->get();
```

Try this code @Aishan